# Getting error "The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT "

Tags: wordpress

i am newbie in wordpress. i have created my own plugin and it's working fine for me... now i have created **rar/zip** file my plugin folder... i am uploading my plugin **.rar** file in my another wordpress project...

it's giving error

```
The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature
```

through FTP it's working fine in my all wordpress projects... but i want to make it uploadable.

my plugin file structure is :--

**/mypluging_dir**

```
 **--images---** 
 **--css--**
 **--pluginfile.php--**
 **--abc.php--**
 **--xyz.php--**
```

i am using xampp 3.2.1 and my wordpress version is 3.7.1

Any help will be appreciate..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the wordpress standard you have to upload **.zip** file only... as you mentioned in your question **.rar**.. it won't get upload...

Try to convert in to the **.zip** format and try... surely it will get upload...

after that if still you are getting error let me know..

hope it may help you...

Answer (score 2):

A long time ago, i used to use wordpress. But i remember, you can't use RAR format for your plugin. You try using ZIP format for your plugin. Good luck